# JSON object in json array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to put the objects in array and then in a spinner (caracteristici) response gets the information. The project stoped when it should to put them in array.

```
    try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray caracteristiciArray = jObj.getJSONArray(Constants.TAG_CARACTERISTICI);
                    caracteristici.clear(); 
                   for (int i = 0; i < caracteristiciArray.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject c = caracteristiciArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       caracteristici.add(new Caracteristici(c.getString(Constants.TAG_CARACTERIZARE),     c.getString(Constants.TAG_STATISTICA)));
```

> response: {"clasa_caracterizare":[{"denumire_caracterizare":"Adezivi
>   Si
>   Lacuri"},{"denumire_caracterizare":"Materiale"},{"denumire_caracterizare":"Altele"}]}....

Comment: use logcat to see what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

You try to extract Constants.TAG_CARACTERIZARE and Constants.TAG_STATISTICA - but the objects all only have one string element - unless Constants.TAG_CARACTERIZARE is equal to Constants.TAG_STATISTICA - this will fail

Comment: The array caracteristiciArray is empty, it does not take informations.

Comment: yea because it will go in the catch branch for a ElementNotFoundException